# when tab bar background switch to dark, change tab bar items border color also

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have small SwiftUI app, tab bar items have two color, selected have blue color and unselected have gray color and when I click the tab bar items , background switching to the dark color,  and I want to change tab bar items border color like selected will have blue color, unselected will have red color when background switch to dark color , is it possible?

**DemoView:**

```
struct DemoView: View {

    let tabBar = UITabBar.appearance()

    init() {
        tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    }

    @State private var selectedTab = 0    // preserves selected tab

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("FirstView")
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "homekit")
                    Text("First")
                }.tag(0)
            
            Text("SecondView")
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "heart")
                    Text("Second")
                }.tag(1)
            Text("ThirdView")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "video")
                    Text("Third")
                    
                }.tag(2)
        }
        
        .onAppear {
            setTabViewBackground()  // called, because `id` is below
        }
        .id(selectedTab)   // recreates entire above view with new tabbar
         
    }

    func setTabViewBackground() {
        tabBar.barTintColor = selectedTab != 0 ? .black : .white
           
    }
}
```

**screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change/add the following to your `setTabViewBackground()` method.

```
func setTabViewBackground() {
    tabBar.barTintColor = selectedTab != 0 ? .black : .white
    // Add the following line and change to your needs
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor =  selectedTab != 0 ? .red : .gray
}
```

See the results below

[image]